# Energy Source for Gamma Rays from Merging Neutron Stars

Tags: neutron-star, gamma-ray-bursts

When the two neutron stars merged in the latest event, large amounts of gamma rays were emitted.  Given that their deorbitting is a result of gravitational wave production, where does the energy for the gamma rays come from?

The only sources I can think of are the rotational kinetic energies of the merging stars or the potential energy released by the final collapse into a single spherical mass.

Answer (score 3):

**Not** Nuclear fusion;
There is also a huge amount of nuclear fusion that **creates heavy elements** from all the iron there is in neutron star: they in fact are not only made of neutrons. But as said in comment, building of heavier elements rather consumes energy than it generates some.

Not sure scientists  has a clear agreement on how this works.

**Gravitational collapse**

For example I found [this (rather old) abstract](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/1779936_Red_Hole_Gamma-Ray_Bursts_A_New_Gravitational_Collapse_Paradigm_Explains_the_Peak_Energy_Distribution_and_Solves_the_GRB_Energy_Crisis) which states it could be a result of [gravitational collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_collapse), without singularity (since here the result of the merger might not be a black-hole, or the lightest ever: [around 2.7 solar masses](https://www.space.com/38471-gravitational-waves-neutron-star-crashes-discovery-explained.html)!)

> theoretical developments (string theory, quantum gravity, critical collapse), which suggest that complete gravitational collapse can occur without singularities or event horizons

**Thermonuclear event again: fission**

[From Space.com](https://www.space.com/22231-gamma-ray-bursts-neutron-stars.html), they say Kilonova energy could be explained by rapid atomic decay of heavy elements

> The mergers of dense cosmic bodies that are thought to cause short gamma-ray bursts can also blast out neutron-rich gas that rapidly generates heavy elements such as gold and platinum, scientists say. These "r-process" elements can undergo radioactive decay and release an enormous amount of energy — 1,000 times or so that given off by stellar explosions such as novas. These powerful events are thus known as "kilonovas"

Comment: My understanding is that fusion of elements heavier than iron absorbs energy rather than emitting it?  I would think there would be another mechanism for turning the potential and kinetic energy of the colliding neutron stars into gamma ray emission (really, really hot accretion disk?)

Comment: I read the article on gravitational collapse you mentioned. It would have been nice to see a mathematical treatment that justifies the posited "red hole" the author describes or at least a citation to such. Without that, it's difficult to see that as a likely scenario.  I do like the idea that some of the matter from one or both stars is ejected as that address with the spectral analysis that shows heavier elements in the mix.